# ¿Cómo comprueba si hay registro en una consulta mysql desde php y si no existe muestre otra cosa?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web, y en ella hay un buscador, buscas un id y te muestra la información de ese id, pero si ponen un id que no existe en la base de datos, te muestra la pagina en blanco, lo que quiero es que cuando busquen un id que no exista muestre un mensaje que diga que ese id no existe, o algo así, espero me entiendan, igual y les dejo un poco del codigo:

```
  <?php
   $var = $_POST["id"];
   $consulta= "SELECT * FROM usuarios where id = $var";
   $row = mysql_query($lnk,$consulta);
   $fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)

  ?>

  <form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="nombre" value="<?php echo $fila['nombre'];?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="apellido" id="apellido" name="apelllido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo $fila['apellido'];?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="correo" name="correo" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo electronico" value="<?php echo $fila['correo'];?>">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con una condición, por ejemplo:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($vaiablequecontienetuconsulta) == 0){
 echo " El ID que ingresaste no existe en la base de datos, intenta con uno diferente ";
}else{
 // Aqui va la operacion que tienes ya hecha para mostrar el resultado
}
```